# Jolt Transform in NiFi to bump an array up a level

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

Running NiFi 1.23.2.a

I need to shift an array up a level in JSON.

Input:

```json
[
 "count": 50,
 "ins": {
   "in": [
      {"type": "value1", "required": "true"},
      {"type": "value2", "required": "true"}
    ]
  }
]
```

What I want to get it to:

```json
{
 "count": 50,
 "in": {
      {"type": "value1", "required": "true"},
      {"type": "value2", "required": "true"}
  }
}
```

Current JoltTransform (worked before we upgraded from NiFi v1.19 to 1.23):

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "count": "count",
        "ins": {
          "*": {
            "in": "in"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi. The input and the output values are not valid JSONs.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the input and output JSON values are not valid in the current case, presumably you're looking for this transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "count": "&",
        "ins": { "*": "&" } // name the whole content by the current node's key through use of ampersand
      }
    }
  }
]
```

or this one

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "count": "count",
        "@ins.in": "in" // direct path definition
      }
    }
  }
]
```